# Why does the VBA Userform progress bar update every time that is it clicked?

Tags: vba, userform

**Here's my problem:**

I have a Userform Progress Bar that is intended to update the "% Completed" after each iteration of a For loop. However, when the Userform is clicked, the "% Completed" bar and value increment. I'm not sure why it does this and it appears to be only cosmetic but it's important that the "% Completed" bar and value match the present iteration status.

Is there a way to prevent this from occurring if the window is accidently clicked during the calculation?

[image]

**Code:**

```
Sub helpme()

Dim x As Long, y As Long, i As Double, j As Double, p As Double, q As Double
Dim max As Integer, max2 As Integer, maxTotal As Integer
Dim pctComp As Single
Dim startTime As Double
Dim runTime As Double
Dim sh As Worksheet

'Error handling for debugging

Dim errorCount As Long
Dim totalErrorCount As Long

x = 11
y = 11
max = InputBox("How many batches are we evaluating?", "Batch Range")
max2 = max
maxTotal = max + max2

For Each sh In Worksheets
    Calculate
    errorCount = ErrorCheck(sh.Range("A1:ZZ1000"))
            
    If errorCount > 0 Then
    
        MsgBox sh.Name & ": " & errorCount & " " & "error(s)"
        
    End If
    
    totalErrorCount = totalErrorCount + errorCount
    
Next

MsgBox "There are" & "  " & totalErrorCount & "  " & "in workbook"


startTime = Timer       
runTime = Timer
DoEvents

For i = 4 To max

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    'Calculate

    With Sheets("Calc").Cells(3, x + 22).Resize(248, 11)
        .Value = Sheets("Calc").Cells(3, 22).Resize(248, 11).FormulaR1C1
        
    End With
    
    x = x + 11
    
    runTime = Timer
            
    pctComp = Round((i / maxTotal) * 100, 1)
    Progress pctComp
    CalcClock runTime, startTime
    
    Calculate
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.StatusBar = "Calculating Cascade Series I: " & i & " of " & max & ":" & Format(i / max, "     " & "0%")
    
    'ClearData.SetText Text:=Empty
    'ClearData.PutInClipboard
    
                      
Next i

For j = 4 To max2

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    'Calculate

    With Sheets("Calc2").Cells(3, y + 22).Resize(248, 11)
        .Value = Sheets("Calc2").Cells(3, 22).Resize(248, 11).FormulaR1C1

    End With
    
    y = y + 11
                                 
    runTime = Timer

    pctComp = Round(((i + j) / maxTotal) * 100, 1)
    
    If pctComp > 100 Then
        pctComp = 100
        
    End If
    
    Progress pctComp
    CalcClock runTime, startTime
    
    Calculate
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.StatusBar = "Calculating Cascade Series II: " & j & " of " & max2 & ":" & Format(j / max2, "     " & "0%")
    

Next j
```

**Here is the UserForm code:**

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.StatusBar = False

    End

End Sub

Private Sub Frame1_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub Text1_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub Text2_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Activate()

    helpme

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.StatusBar = False

    End
    
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_End()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.StatusBar = False

    Unload.Me

End Sub
```

Comment: Try and repaint the form after you update the progressbar and see if that makes any difference?

Comment: Clicking a window gives the program a CPU boost.

Comment: @user14797724 is there anyway to replicate that outside of physically clicking the window to speed everything up overall? I'm looking to optimize this further.

Comment: Your computer would need to be busy for it to make a difference. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/priority-boosts.